# Is it OK to run 48 GB RAM on a Ryzen Win64 system?

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have a Windows 10 system powered by a Ryzen 5 2600X. When I built it, I set it up with 16GB of dual-channel RAM (8x2 sticks). Now it's giving me messages that memory is low, and I notice that at bootup, only 7.93GB is available. I'd like to buy 32GB more to alleviate this. Is there any problem with running a Windows 10 system with this slightly unusual amount of RAM? The kit I'm planning to buy is from the same manufacturer, same specs except it's 16x2.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem with running a Windows 10 system with this slightly unusual amount of RAM?

The memory limitation of `Windows 10 Home` is **128 GB**.  The memory limitation of `Windows 10 Professional` is **2 TB**.

> [image]

Source: [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical-memory-limits-windows-10)

> I have a Windows 10 system powered by a Ryzen 5 2600X. When I built it, I set it up with 16GB of dual-channel RAM (8x2 sticks). Now it's giving me messages that memory is low, and I notice that at bootup, only 7.93GB is available.

Sounds like you have a memory leak, additional memory, will not actually solve that particular problem.

Most people confuse the warning message about low virtual memory as an indication they are running out of physical memory, verify this the message you received, isn't actually talking about virtual memory.  **If it is all you have to do is allow Windows to manage your page file.**

Comment: While the memory limitation of Windows 10 is 128 GB your hardware might support a great deal less.  There are very few motherboards on the market that support 128 GB (4x32GB) most motherboards supports 64 GB or less.

Comment: If you have memory allocated to Hardware Reserved you should disable that in the firmware (or at least lower it).